# Save attachments NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pop3

I'm using a NodeJS library(yapople) to read emails from my pop3 server.  The problem I'm coming across is downloading the attachments.  Not sure how to exactly do this.  I get back a mailparser object where I see the attachments. This is what I have so far.

```
var fs = require('fs');
const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;

var Client = require('yapople').Client;
var client = new Client({
  hostname: 'xxxxxxx',
  port:  995,
  tls: true,
  mailparser: true,
  username: 'xxxxx',
  password: 'xxxxx'
});

client.connect(function() {

    //I get an email with attachments
    client.retrieve(4327, function(err, messages){
        if(messages.attachments != null){
        for (var i in messages.attachments) {
            var attachment = messages.attachments[i];
            var data = attachment.content;
            fs.writeFile(attachment.fileName, data)
        }
    }

    })
    client.quit();
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown [here](https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/#attachment-object), an `attachment` object has `content` which is a `Buffer`.

`messages.attachments[0].content` should give you the file (as a `Buffer`).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Right I got that far where I see its a Uint8Array(17653) [80, 75, 3, 4, 20, 0, 6, 0, …].  The problem i'm having is saving that using nodejs. Any ideas?  I think I'm a bit lost on how nodemailer works.

Comment: You are right.  All I needed to do was fs.writeFile(attachment.fileName, data).  I updated my original response.

Comment: You probably don't want to use the send provided filename.  You may overwrite a file, or it may contain bad characters....